# Does there exist a bounded measure for a certain stochastic process which follows a non-semigroup algebraic structure?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

It is known that if we have a Markov process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$, then for all bounded measurable $f$ and for all $s,t \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a bounded measure $P_sf$ such that
$$
E[f(X_{t + s}) \mid (X_r)_{r \leq t}] 
=
(P_sf)(X_t).
$$
Then, we know that if $\mu$ is a stationary measure for the Markov process, $P_t$ follows a semi-group property:
$$
P_{t+s}f = P_tP_sf,
$$
$\mu$-a.s.

**My question:** The Markov process has a bounded measure which has a semi-group structure. Are there other stochastic processes which follow, say, a ring structure? Are algebraic structures exploited more in certain areas of stochastic analysis? I have heard that representation theory arises somehow (I believe in the MCMC literature for walks on groups).

Comment: The semi-group structure only requires one associative operation, not even having invertibility; but rings require two operations, one commutative and invertible and another one being a monoid. Maybe all these structures are too much to ask for in the transition operator... On one hand, the semi-group you mentioned is actually a monoid because $P_0$ is an identity element, but on the other hand, I suspect (intuitively) we can't hope for an inverse element to always exist unless we restrict ourselves to consider only some peculiar processes, can we...?